# Bind pdo variables in for/foreach loop

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have looked at some other Stack Overflow questions on this, but I can't figure out how to loop through sql statements and bind variables to that. Here is how my queries look right now:

```
$db = dbCon();
$sql = "";
foreach($data as $d) {
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO required_fields (field_name) VALUES ($d)";
}
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
// Here is where I need to bind the variables
$stmt->execute();
$rowsChanged = $stmt->rowCount();
$stmt->closeCursor();
return $rowsChanged;
```

I can't figure out how to loop through because this is how I understand bindValue works:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':variableInQuery', $PHPVariable, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

What's tripping me up is the colon in front of the variableInQuery and I can't figure out how to make the php variable name unique...what am I missing?

Comment: Do the inserts one at a time. Move the prepare before the `foreach` and `bind` and `execute` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code inside the loop:

```
<?php
$db = dbCon();
$sql = "INSERT INTO required_fields (field_name) VALUES (:variableInQuery)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$rowsChanged = 0;
foreach($data as $d) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':variableInQuery', $d, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rowsChanged += $stmt->rowCount();
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
return $rowsChanged;
```

Comment: you should also move the `prepare()` just before `foreach()`

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale Hi yea very good point, thanks, I have also moved `closeCursor` to the outside what do you think?